# Remove site header and footer inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a website that contains a category page. I want to include this category page in the home page but without the header and footer when it is in the iframe. But, if a user accesses it from its URL it should show the full page. Also, have the iframe resize to be the same height and width as the page.

I have tried to load the iframe and remove the header and footer but the problem is:

1. The resize function doesn't work because the resize function calculates the header and the footer before removed
2. It appears as a full webpage with the header and the footer then it removed

Comment: In your so-called iframe script, check if (window.parent === window), if that is true, then your page is NOT in iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You would use either the backend of the site or your JavaScript/jQuery to detect if there is a parameter in your iFrames link(ie. www.yoursite.com/pagename?hide=true), which will hide the footer and header if hide=true.

For size issue you can apply the below changes

If you have given an id to iframe then use this css or apply inline css

`#myIframe
{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%; 
}`

Below is the logic for getting variable passed in url using jquery

`// Get all variables from a url and return them as an associative array.
function getVariableFromURL()
{
    var variables = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        variables.push(hash[0]);
        variables[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return variables;
}`

For example, if you have the URL:

`http://www.yoursite.com/?param1=Value1&param=Value2`

The output will be as below:

`{
    "param1"    : "Value1",
    "param2" : "Value2"
}`

and you can fetch as below:

`var param1 = getVariableFromURL()["param1"];
var param2 = getVariableFromURL()["param2"];`

Comment: i dont care about the variable i care about your first 3 lines how to do this pleaze